# Page number in Page-Based Interface with WatchKit (Watch)?

Tags: xcode, swift, interface-builder, watchkit, apple-watch

I created a WatchKit app with a [Page-Based Interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/InterfaceStyles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH12-SW1).

There are 3 pages and each one is connected to my **InterfaceController.swift** class (which extends **WKInterfaceController**).

My question: inside InterfaceController.swift how can I detect the page number of the current view?

Answer (score 2):

If you use

```
func presentControllerWithNames(_ names: [AnyObject],
                   contexts contexts: [AnyObject]?)
```

You just have to pass the number of the page in the context, so you can store it, and retrieve it later on. This is the non storyboard way.

If you use storyboard, it is the same, you just have to use the other method

```
func contextsForSegueWithIdentifier(_:inTable:rowIndex:)
```

And pass your page index in the context of each controller

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using Storyboard and I did and override of ***contextsForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String) -> [AnyObject]?*** and ***contextForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String, inTable table: WKInterfaceTable, rowIndex: Int) -> AnyObject?*** in my InterfaceController.swift. But these method are not called when I change page in the Simulator.

Comment: You need to make a modal Segue. A PageController needs to be modal. Did you do that ?

Comment: Yes, I did it via Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved this way,

Present InterfaceController in pageNavigation with **Appropriate Context Values**,

```
[self presentControllerWithNames:@[@"TestInterfaceController",@"TestInterfaceController",@"TestInterfaceController"] contexts:@[@"Page 1",@"Page 2",@"Page 3"]];
```

Then create a NSString property to track page and label to display it,

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *currentContext;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceLabel *pageLabel;
```

In awakeWithContext assign it to NSString property,

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];

    NSLog(@"%@",context);
    self.currentContext = context;
}
```

Display it on willActive,

```
- (void)willActivate {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    [super willActivate];

    NSLog(@"%@ willActivate",self.currentContext);
    [self.pageLabel setText:self.currentContext];
}
```

You can also detect when page didDeactivate,

```
- (void)didDeactivate {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
    [super didDeactivate];
    NSLog(@"%@ didDeactivate",self.currentContext);
}
```

**Edit :**
If page navigations are configured using Storyboard Segue then override this method in Source IntefaceController from where you created model segue to destination controller to provide contexts,

```
- (NSArray *)contextsForSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)segueIdentifier {
    NSArray *contexts = nil;
    if ([segueIdentifier isEqualToString:@"MyPageNavigation"]) {
        contexts = @[@"Page 1",@"Page 2",@"Page 3"];
    }

    return contexts;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The last 4 code blocks go inside the `InterfaceController` class. But where should I put the instruction in your first block of code?

Comment: You need to put that in Source InterfaceController controller from where you are presenting your destination TestInterfaceController. May be any button action depending on your implementation.

Comment: Please note that the UI is totally managed via a Page-Based Storyboard. There are 3 InterfaceController(s) and they are connected by a "next-page" relationship. I am not loading the next InterfaceController via code.